# How to make object by pointer in const object constant?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, transitive-const

```
class Foo {
public:
    int a = 1;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Foo *foo_ptr = new Foo;
};

int main() {
    const Bar bar;
    bar.foo_ptr.a++;        //   valid: a == 2
    bar.foo_ptr = nullptr;  // invalid: foo_ptr is const
}
```

I understand, why code above is correct - object `bar` is constant, so `foo_ptr` is constant pointer to a non-const `Foo` object. But I think it's a bit illogical. Why `Foo` object also did not become const?

What should I do, if I want `Bar` object to become absolute `const` here, and the `foo_ptr` to be a constant pointer to a constant object?

For example, I send `Bar` object to some method, and I don't want it or any `Foo` objects in it to be modifiable.

Comment: Regarding the pointer class member variable, `mutable` might come in handy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think the dupe does not address the OP's concern. I think they want to be able to use `bar.foo_ptr.a++;` when `bar` is not `const` while disallowing it when `bar` is `const`.

Comment: @RSahu I believe such could be done providing appropriate getter/setter functions varying from the instances `const` nature, instead of just making the raw pointer member variable `public`. Anyways understanding the difference of a `const` pointer vs a pointer to a `const` object lays out the basis knowledge, how to implement such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, exactly. They need appropriate `public` functions and not expose the pointer as a `public` member variable. Understanding `const` pointer vs pointer to `const` object is necessary but that does not necessarily help with their objective, assuming we, including the OP, are on the  same page on the objective.

Comment: @RSahu Maybe sometime's I am implying too much and are step beyond how to solve the obvious compiler error. :-/ feel free to reopen the question.

Comment: well, it behaves exactly as you defined it. if you do not want foo changed, make it const. btw: you are leaking memory. Stop using owning raw pointers.

Comment: @skeller _"Stop using owning raw pointers."_ .., and if you really need them don't make these public member variables.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I agree, it would be better to make `foo_ptr` private, but suddenly class `Bar` is not mine. It was created automatically by QT framework.

Comment: @RSahu you're right, I want to disallow `bar.foo_ptr.a++;` when `bar` is const.

Comment: @DmitryPaliy _"but suddenly class Bar is not mine. It was created automatically by QT framework."_ Consider wrapping such stuff with [_smart pointer_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) class members, be it a simple `std::weak_ptr` implementation, if those instances are completely beyond your control. I am pretty sure such stuff is also considered in the Qt Framework and you have better choice to refer to other components than a public raw pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I think it's a bit illogical. Why `Foo` object also did not become `const`?

The compiler cannot assume how far to extend the notion of `const`. You, as the designer of `Bar`, have to help the compiler with that. You can do that by making the member variable `private` and providing `public` interfaces that preserve the `const`-ness of the object that the pointer points to.

Update your class to:

```
class Bar {
   public:
      Foo* getFoo();
      Foo const* getFoo() const;

   private:
      Foo *foo_ptr = new Foo;
};
```

and now

```
int main() {

    const Bar bar1;
    bar1.getFoo()->a++;  // Not OK. Compiler error.

    Bar bar2;
    bar2.getFoo()->a++;  // OK.
}
```

Comment: use a std::unique_ptr for "foo_ptr" to prevent it leaking memory :)

Comment: @skeller, or not use pointers for these silly objects at all. The crux of my post is to show how to define the notion of `const` for a user defined type and not get that  diluted by other concerns.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you might use value instead of pointer:

```
class Bar {
public:
    Foo foo;
};
```

then `bar.foo` would be const when `bar` is

If you really need "pointer", you might use [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

```
class Bar {
public:
    std::experimental::propagate_const<Foo*> foo_ptr = new Foo; // work also with smart pointers
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfa681c4c378f82c)