# why is std::basic_ostream::operator<< not const-qualified?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, ostream

First, an example to illustrate the morals behind my question: the below code will not compile, because std::basic_ostream::operator<< is not `const`-qualified. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/ostream-source.html shows that the operator is not `const`-qualified.)

I compiled with GNU g++ 6.4.0 compiler, with --std=c++11 flag on.

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class ChessPiece{
    const string name;
    const int side;
public:
    ChessPiece(const string&,const int);
    void printPiece(const ostream&) const;
};
#endif // TEST_H
```

...and test.cpp.

```
#include"test.h"
ChessPiece::ChessPiece(const string& s,const int bw): name{s}, side{bw} {}
void ChessPiece::printPiece(const ostream& S=cout) const{
    S << "a " << (side==1?"white ":"black ") << name << endl;
}
int main(){
    ChessPiece p{string("pawn"),-1}; // a black pawn
    p.printPiece();
}
```

However, I am not sure as to why these kind of errors should occur in the first place, even though operator<< is, as in the above code, logically `const`.
Yes, the obvious answer would be that "`operator<<` changes the inner state of `std::ostream` in some way".

However, I know that by making the members `mutable` we can change the contents of the class, as long as the `const`-qualified function is logically `const`. I also know that an instance of `std::ostream` will not logically differ in any way before and after calling its `operator<<`. *(If anything I wrote is wrong, please point it out. Thank you)*

Rephrased,

**Why is the logically `const` std::basic_ostream::operator<< not `const`-qualified, instead of having some of its members mutable?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short answer: because `operator<<` changes state of `std::ostream` object and instance will be logically differ indeed.

Comment: It would be very surprising if a `const std::stringstream` could be printed to, for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> I also know that an instance of `std::ostream` will not logically differ in any way before and after calling its `operator<<`.

That's one way to look at an `std::ostream`. Another way to look at it is that it is an interface to a device -- a file, a console, a string, etc. If a member function in that interface changes the underlying device, it is misleading to make that member function a `const` member function.

The notion of `const` is conceptual. Take a look at [one my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51525802/434551) that explores the subject a bit. Yes, one could have made the `operator<<` functions work with `const std::stream` objects but it makes more sense that they are not. They are changing the underlying device that they provide an interface for and, IMO, it's better that they work with non-`const` objects of type `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ostream` *will* differ after calling its `operator<<`, in externally visible ways. Most of the time, the `tellp` method will return an updated value (and similarly, the result of `seekp` using `cur` as the second argument will differ).

Even if it's a stream output (so "position" is a meaningless concept), the various status bits can always change, and again, are part of the externally visible state through the `good`, `bad`, `fail` and `eof` methods.

Further, the buffer of an `ostream` has behaviors (including the ability to be completely swapped out) that will differ unpredictably as things are written to it. Swapping out a backing buffer behaves completely differently depending on whether it is empty or not; if non-empty, data someone wrote won't be written. Since writing more data of any kind can switch from empty to non-empty buffer state (writing less than buffer size bytes to an empty buffer with no implicit flush), and from non-empty to empty (if a flush is triggered by filling the buffer or a newline on a line buffered stream), you're always mutating the visible state of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at such code:

```
os << data;
if( !os ) throw std::runtime_exception( "io error" );
```

though result of `operator<<` is usually ignored one may need to check that output was successful. Most probably compiler will not be able to optimize out this check, but for me as a reader it becomes unclear, why do I need to recheck state of the object after `const` method called. So marking these methods `const` will harm readability of interface and will not make any good and clearly these calls are not `const` by concept.

Note: mutable members added for ability to optimize `const` method calls without changing observable behavior (cache result of expensive operation and return cached value if state of the object did not change), using `mutable` here would be simple abuse of `const` method concept