# Why can I call member's non-const function inside const member function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constants

When I compile below code using VisualStudio 2015, I get C2662 compiler error only on `GetValueUsingObject()` member function.

Code:

```
class Member
{
public:
    int GetValue() { _value = 1; return _value; }

private:
    int _value;
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() : _pointer(new Member()) {}
    int GetValueUsingPointer() const { return _pointer->GetValue(); } // Okay
    int GetValueUsingObject() const { return _object.GetValue(); }    // C2662 Error

private:
    Member* _pointer;
    Member _object;
};
```

Compile Error Message:

> C2662 'int Member::GetValue(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Member' to 'Member &'

I think that both `GetValueUsingPointer()` and `GetValueUsingObject()` function violates const-ness. But, `GetValueUsingPointer()` has no compiling issue.

Why is it Okay?

Comment: When a `Test` object is `const`, that means that its member `_pointer` cannot be changed. But `GetValueUsingPointer` doesn't change `_pointer`. It still points to whatever it pointed to before. `_pointer` is acting as a `const` pointer to a non-`const` `Member`, not a `const` pointer to a `const Member`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's really a canonical duplicate of this question, but issues related to it come up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525316/how-to-make-object-by-pointer-in-const-object-constant), for instance.

Comment: `const` affects the variable. `Member _object;` -> `Member const _object;`. `Member* _pointer;` -> `Member* const _pointer;`.

Comment: If you want to extend the constness of `Test` to the object its pointer points, add a pair of accessor overloads: `const Member& get() const { return *_pointer; }` and `Member& get() { return *_pointer; }` and then `int GetValueUsingPointer() const { return get().GetValue(); }` will fail. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/aPbr49Ydq)

Comment: All about [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't calling the members function. You use a member pointer (that is `const`), dereference it, and call a member function of the object the pointer points to. And that object is not `const`.

If pointers confuse you, consider an example where you have a member that is index into a global array:

```
std::array<int,42> memory;

struct foo {
    size_t index = 23;
    void bar() const {
        memory[index] = 0;  // does not modify index
    }
};
```

A `const foo` has a constant `index`, but you can use that `index` to access the `index`-th element in `memory` and modify it:

You can imagine pointers as index into memory. A pointer that is constant does not mean that what is stored in that memory is constant. You can have a non-const pointer to constant object, const pointer to non-constant object, etc. In your constant `Test` the member `_pointer` is constant, the object it points to is not.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
private:
    Member* _pointer;
```

declares a pointer to *some* object of the `Member` class.

The `_pointer` is a member of your `*this` object and as such it is treated as `const` pointer. However, the declaration of `_pointer` is

```
    Member* _pointer;
```

and not

```
    const Member* _pointer;
```

or

```
    Member const* _pointer;
```

so the object pointed at is not declared as `const`.

As a result you have a const pointer to a non-const object. Your expression

```
    _pointer->GetValue()
```

implies the pointed object may be modified, but it is allowed, hence no error on the right side of the `->` operator.
OTOH, it does not imply any action modifying the const `_pointer` member, hence no error on the left side, either.

Answer (score 1):

The member is a pointer, which itself remains unchanged. What changes is an object it points to. Therefore it is valid to modify the pointee. Same stands for references.
If const should also mean "pure" is an open question.
If for for some reason you'd like to ensure the constness of parent object propagates also to its pointees, you need to propagate the constness to the pointee object, e.g. by wrapping the pointer/reference into the appropriate class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct ConstPropagatingPtr
{
    //open question if that should be explicit or not
    /*explicit*/ConstPropagatingPtr(T* p) : contents(p) {}
    ConstPropagatingPtr(ConstPropagatingPtr&) = default;
    ConstPropagatingPtr& operator=(ConstPropagatingPtr&) = default;
    ConstPropagatingPtr& operator=(T* p) { contents = p; return *this; }
    T& operator*() { return *contents; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *contents; }
    const T* getRaw() const { return contents;}
    T* getRaw() { return contents;}
    const T* operator->() const { return contents;}
    T* operator->() { return contents;}
    explicit operator bool() const { return contents != nullptr; }

private:
    T* contents;
};

//example
struct P
{
    void doStuffNonConst() {}
    void doStuffConst() const {}
};

struct S
{
    S() : pptr(new P) {}
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S& operator=(const S&) = delete;
    ConstPropagatingPtr<P> pptr;

    void constMember() const { pptr->doStuffConst(); }
    void anotherConstMember() const
    { 
        //oops! compilation error!
        //pptr->doStuffNonConst();
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vcz4o455Y

Similar wrappers should be provided for references and smart pointers should those be needed. For the sake of the example I have covered only the most basic case.

You can also have a look at [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const).